# Why do we make a distinction between a quasi-linear PDE and a non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm taking a class on numerical methods which is currently focusing on the classification of quasi-linear PDEs defined as follows:

> A Partial Differential Equation is considered quasi-linear if the coefficients of the highest order derivatives are functions of the independent variables and lower-order derivatives of the dependent variables.

By this definition PDEs like the Navier-Stokes equations, famous for their non-linear behaviors, are classified as quasi-linear.

Can anyone explain to me why we make this distinction between non-linear and quasi-linear PDEs?  The distinction made above seems sort of arbitrary.  (I could define a "quadratic-quasi-linear" PDE classification in which the equation must be linear with regard to the square of the highest order derivatives... but to what end.)

I assume that quasi-linear PDEs have some set of distinct features that make them worth setting aside as a separate classification.  Can anyone offer an explanation of why this distinction is being made?

Thank you.